# Select rows that don't exist in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: SQL Tables]
Let's suppose I have 4 tables as above. BOM means Bill of Materials. As you can see, Production Order 1 is missing 1 item from it's BOM (ITEM3) and Production Order 2 is missing other item (ITEM1). Given a BOM code, how do I get every production order that is missing an item and which item is that? The result would be something like:

```
ID | Item
---|------
1  | ITEM3
2  | ITEM1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT id, item
  FROM production_order po
      JOIN bom_items bi ON po.code = bi.father
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT 1 FROM production_oder_items poi
       WHERE poi.id = po.id
         AND poi.item = bi.item)
  AND po.code = 'CAR01';
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to determine all the production order item combinations.  Then use a `left join` to determine the ones that are not there:

```
select po.Production_Order, bi.item
from Production_Order po cross join
     BOM_Items bi left join
     Product_Order_Items poi
     on poi.Production_order = po.id and
        poi.Item = bi.Item
where poi.Item is null;
```

Comment: Seems good but where do I put the WHERE clause to determine the BOM Code? Like (WHERE po.Code = 'CAR01')

Comment: @ruda . . . You would add that to the WHERE clause.

Comment: I tried something like (where poi.Item is null and po.Code = 'CAR01') and it's returning many rows. The second column in the select is bringing wrong values.